# VS2015 Nuget error but not using Nuget at all

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, compiler-errors, nuget-package-restore

Yesterday i upgraded from visual studio 2010 to vs2015. I have an existing project, a simple Windows Forms application that used to build without problem. Now when building the project in VS2015 i get Error while restoring Nuget packages, HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY).

I'm not using Nuget, don't know what Nuget is, have no nuget package folder in my project, so don't have the slightest idea what goes wrong.

Searched a lot for solutions but they all seem to refer to problems *using* packages, not to problems with *not* using packages.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: More info: just tried creating a new project. Same error message (now in a msgbox). How to find out *what* DLL is missing?

Comment: Can you list the reference that the project currently has? And did you migrate to a new version of the .Net framework as well?

Comment: The error occurs even when just creating a new project.

Comment: Found errrors in activityLog: **TMLanguage.dll** not found but it *is* there. Idem for Microsoft.VisualStudio.ApplicationInsights.dll

Comment: @vbnet3d Regarding dotnet: Had a newer verion of dotnet which gave installation error. After full uninstall of both vs2010 and 2015 I also uninstalled the dotnet4. Now VS2015 install was ok, no errors. But the dll related errors remain

Comment: Decided to abandon this question, will post a new one detailing the errors in ActivityLog.